# RSpec strange behaviour: doesn't see controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have hierarchy of my Controllers

```
Backend::ProductsController < Backend::ModelController < Backend::BackendController < ApplicationController
```

create action defined in Backend::ModelController

In development and production mode even in standart rails test every thing wortks just fine.

Wrote rspec features, integration test, with using rspec capybara selenium and puma or WebRick.

And when I submit my form in spec, I got

```
<AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create' could not be found for Backend::ProductsController>
```

When I added action defenition to Backend::ProductsController

```
def create
  super
end
```

It works in Rspec too.

So my question is: why rspec does not see create action in Backend::ModelController ?

[app/controllers/backend/model_controller.rb](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23954002/)

```
class Backend::ModelController < Backend::BackendController
  before_action :set_object,      only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :convert]
  respond_to :html, :js, :json
  attr_reader :model, :model_name, :index_path

  include Backend::FormsHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

...    
  def create
    @object = model.new(request_params)

    if @object.save
      flash[:success] = I18n.t("status.created", resource: I18n.t("#{model_name}.one"), title: "<strong>#{@object}</strong>")
    end

    instance_variable_set("@#{model_name}", @object)
    index_path = eval("#{model_name.pluralize}_path(session['#{model_name}_index_params'])")
    respond_with(@object, location: index_path, action: "#{model_name}")
  end
...
end
```

[app/controllers/backend/products_controller.rb](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23954003/)

```
class Backend::ProductsController < Backend::ModelController
  before_action only: [:new,  :create] { @tab_list = "generals descriptions parameters" }
  before_action only: [:edit, :update] { @tab_list = "generals descriptions parameters banners specifications competitions photos attachments redirections" }

  def new
    flash[:info] = t('product.save_required')
    super
    flash.clear
  end

def 
  super
end

  def edit
    @product.control_specifications
    super
  end

  def update
    old_cache_key = @product.cache_key
    super
    if params[:novelty] == "true"
      @product.update_columns(created_at: Time.now)
      @product.update_columns(top_sale: false)
    end
    @product.touch_gently if old_cache_key == @product.cache_key
  end


end
```

[rspec log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23954111/)

```
2017-02-08 14:20:02 +0200: Rack app error handling request { POST /backend/products }
#<AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create' could not be found for Backend::ProductsController>
/home/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/home/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionview-5.0.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/home/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
/home/anton/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
...
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question itself - this prevents link rot which makes questions worthless over time.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?